# Не удается запустить приложение в Flask

Tags: python, flask, mac, pip

Не удается запустить приложение в Flask
Когда ввожу в терминале: `python app.py`
Выдается следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Все вроде установлено, и pip и flask.
Может быть что-то упускаю.
п.с. компьютер - mac

Заранее спаси бо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

`flask` для используемого python у вас не установлен. У вас несколько python команд на машине и pip команда запускает не тот python, который вы ожидаете.

Создайте virtualenv и установите flask туда.

Comment: И куда мне потом можно папку с моими файлами для программы поместить?

Comment: @Alex куда хотите—это никак не связанные вещи. Если не понимаете слова "создать virtualenv" или не знаете "как flask внутри virtualenv поставить", то задайте отдельный вопрос, специально об этом.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/  вроде как установила просто используя советы по этой ссылке, но все равно выдается та же ошибка

Comment: @Alex обновите ваш вопрос и по шагам буквально  (начиная с команд для создания и активации virtualenv) покажите как вы flask ставили (приведите все команды и все ошибки/предупреждения, которые они выводят). Будьте уверены приводить точные команды, которые вы фактически использовали, и полный traceback в конце (если он хоть в чём-то отличается от уже приведённого в вопросе).